# js function work on jquery 1.4.3 but not on jquery 1.9.1

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a script for appending a set of input values to a form. Here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var acount = 0;
    $(function(){

    $('a#add_asold').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    acount += 1;

    $('#accsold').append(   
        '<div class="row-fluid">'
        +'<div class="span12" style="border-bottom:1px lightgray solid; padding:5px 0px;">'    

                +'<div class="span3">'
                +'<label>Accessory Sold</label>'
                +'<input id="asold' + acount + '" name="asold' + acount + '" type="text" class="input-medium" />'
                +'</div> '

                +'<div class="span2">'
                +'<label>Price</label>'
                +'<input id="aprice' + acount + '" name="aprice' + acount + '" type="text" class="input-mini" />'
                +'</div>'
                +'<a href="#" id="aremove_field" class="btn btn-inverse btn-mini" style="margin-top:19px;">Delete</a>'                  
                +'<input type="hidden" name="acounter[]" value="1">'
                +'</div>'
        +'</div>'   
        +'</div>'   
         ); 
    $('a#aremove_field').click(function(e) {                                           
    e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent().remove();          
        $('#accsold').append(
        '<input type="hidden" name="acounter[]" value="1">'
        );
    });
    });

});
```

This works fine on 1.4.3 but after upgrading to jquery 1.9.1, I am know getting this error

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$(function(){
```

Any advise would be appreciated, Jquery is loaded before the append script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And your script is placed after the script includes for jQuery?

Comment: yes it is after script includes

Comment: try replacing $ with jQuery ?

Comment: I'd try @user1428716 idea. But it seems like jQuery isn't being included correctly. You're positive the paths are correct, and it's actually loading into the browser?

Comment: yea the paths are correct because is I replace `js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js` with `js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js` it works fine. I'll try user1428716's idea I guess

Comment: try replacing `js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js` with `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js` and see what happens.

Comment: Check the debug info in your browser (eg using Firebug).  That should show the request to load jQuery and whether or not the server returned a successful response.  If the server is a Unix server it could be that when the new jQuery was added the files weren't given world-read permission and thus are not able to be loaded.